# Array of struct whose member is a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this C code for an embedded system where I am assigning  the address of `Var` to an struct pointer member. Problem is when I execute the code I see incorrect address instead of `Var` address in the `structVarArray[1]`. However if I modify the `structVarArray` type to `const` then I get the right address but then I cannot modify the Boolean flag as it becomes `const`. Any idea?

```
UInt8 Var;
typedef struct
{
 UInt8 * ptrVar;
 Boolean flag;
}structType;

structType structVarArray[1] =
// const structType structVarArray[1] =
{
 {&Var,  FALSE}
};

void main(void)
{
 // Code using the above array
}
```

Comment: This sounds unlikely.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like some linker bug. Try to initialize `UInt8 Var=1;`

Comment: @user4419802, global variables are already initialized to `0`, OP, `int main(void)`, please.

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, it's just to check whether this problem due to incorrect handling udata addresses by linker/loader.

Comment: @user4419802, good point, but t is more likely that `// Code using the above array` be the cause

Comment: @AlterMann In embedded systems don't assume globals get initialised to 0 and `void main(void)` is perfectly valid too - There's  no OS to return an int too!@ibrahimdanish Perhaps you're not linking in the correct (or any) C runtime. It's the C runtime's job, generally crt0.o to do static iinitialisation. Please provide more information on the compiler and options used to compile and link.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham, The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be defined with a return type of int** and with no parameters, or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used).

Comment: @AlterMann Thank-you for the standards quote. Exactly what did you fix regarding this question? It's very common to have this prototype in embedded compilers where the C standard becomes a mere guide. There are many compiler specific extensions that give required or extended functionality for the processor architecture too. We need knowledge of the toolchain to help further IMO

Comment: @BrianSidebotham , on systems that doesn’t provide such a facility the returned value is ignored, then why use it incorrectly?

Comment: @Alter Mann, C99 allows void main, you didn't finish the quote: "(5.1.2.2.1) It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... **or in some other implementation-defined manner**". void main is often seen in embedded systems. I guess, it's to emphasize that there's no underlying OS and function should never return.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham - If you have an embedded compiler that doesn't initialise globals to `0`, then it's not a standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Some don't because they expect you to write your own c-runtime and c library stubs. You just can't assume with an embedded compiler, that's all. For example, perhaps it's even gcc and the same could be true *if* the `-nostartfiles` option is being used!

Comment: When compiling for the embedded system are you compiling to a specific target or memory model that would alter the layout or number of segments the compiler is using? I don't know embedded systems, but generally when declared `const` all members would go into re read-only data section instead of data. That would provide different addresses for your struct and `flag`, but `ptrVar` would still reflect the same address.  Have you looked at the differences in the assembler output to check if something funny is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you were attempting to access the structVarArray, below is a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char Var;
struct structType
{
    unsigned char * ptrVar;
    bool flag;
};

structType structVarArray[] =
{
    {&Var, false}
};

int main(void)
{
    *structVarArray[0].ptrVar = 50;

    printf("Var = %d\n", Var);  // prints 50

    structVarArray[0].flag = true;

    return 0;

}
```